# How to prevent CSS inheritance of background color?

Tags: css, inheritance

There is a main page in CSS that inherits this.. but we are allowed to work only in a portal version of the site. We want to change the background color but somehow it is unable to change due to its inheritance from the main CSS. It is a company with many agencies and within that agency there are many depts with different web sites. We belong to one of those department. Suggestions? How to suppress the background or even change the background to a different color. Thanks

Comment: Can you add a class/id (on the body tag maybe?) for your department page, so you can differentiate it from the others?

Comment: `!important` to override main page CSS

Comment: anyway the last solution is using `!important`

Comment: You should try using a more specific selector than you are currently using. Please provide an example of the HTML and CSS that is being used on the element for us to help you further

Comment: *!important* should always/only be used as a last resort.

Comment: Background color is never inherited except when explicitly requested for, with the value `inherit`, so this is not about inheritance at all. Probably some style sheet overriding yours. You really need to give some facts about the situation. Even then, the question might be off-topic; analyzing some live portal isn’t what SO is for.

Comment: sNewbie, were you able to solve the problem? Is your question answered? Consider either *accepting* the provided answer (click the tick mark), providing your own answer and accepting that, or even deleting your question.

Answer (score 3):

From your description, it is really hard to tell what's going on here. However, knowing a bit of CSS, there are usually several things you could try to override rules:

- CSS rules are read from top to bottom; rules that come later (within the same source) will override previous rules
- More specific rules are prioritized over less specific rules. You should be able to override an `p { background-color: #fff; }` with, for example, `#content #main p.note { background-color: #fff; }`
- Inline-Styles (`<tag style="background-color:#fff">...</tag>`) have priority over those in the html's `head` or linked CSS files
- Using `!important` (like this: `background-color:#fff !important;`) will tell the browser to prioritize your rule over other rules

Maybe one of those will do the trick for you.

Comment: Avoid `!important` as it is very bad practice

Comment: @ZachSaucier of course howver sometimes it's the only solution.

Comment: @KingKing *very **very*** rarely that is the case. Hence why we should "avoid" it

Comment: @ZachSaucier if we design the HTML ourselves, we will never need it, however sometimes we can't change the HTML, some libraries provide us the predefined `classes` but to override some properties, we have no other way than using `!important`.